# How to make static callback c++

Tags: c++, function, winapi, static, callback

I have two files, the main one and a class. I want to call a function inside the class(void) and from inside that function call another in the main. Before a lot of searching I found way to do so with a callback and the code ended up like this:

**File**

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo 
{
public:
    std::function<void()> onCallBackResult;
    void start(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
        onCallBackResult = callback;
        second();
    }
    void second() { //Needs to be static here
        onCallBackResult();
    }
};

void onCallBackResult() 
{
    std::cout << "Result\n";
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.start(std::bind(onCallBackResult));
}
```

And it works kinda well, but the problem is that I really need to make the `start` static because it work with WndProc from the Windows api but I cannot make the `onCallBackResult` from the class static too because so I want to know if is there a way to fix this or any other way to call a function from the `main`.

Thank you!

Comment: A class is not a file. A file is not a class.

Comment: `Foo foo = Foo();` Don't do this. Just write `Foo foo;`

Comment: Which part of your example does not work? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/cecfed527cd8c263

Comment: @Amadeus I updated the example with your code and some changes to explain better ma case. If I make "second" static I cannot access onCallBackResult and I cannot make it static too because doesn't allow me.

Comment: Is this what you are trying to achieve? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/515aac13c8b01d36

Comment: If you have a `foo.cpp` file, you can put it there. What it is doing is giving a definition to the static member declaration in `class Foo`.

Comment: Could you please show an example of it? I tried inside and outside the class and it keeps giving the same error C2027

Comment: Nevermind, Now I managed it to work Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

All you need is a prototype. None of that mechanism (`std::bind`, `std::function`) is needed. In "Foo.h":

```
void onCallBackResult();
```

And then change the function to call that one:

```
void start()
{
//Do some tasks
onCallBackResult();
}
```

Comment: The problem is that the main that I want to call will not always be the same function, so I want to specify always which one to use.

Comment: @OnelioD -- you still don't need all that mechanism. Read about "pointer to function".