# c++ Prevent class from sharing static object

Tags: c++, function, class, static

I've some code(from [How to make static callback c++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43982867/how-to-make-static-callback-c)) that I use to access a function in main from a class like this:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

class Foo 
{
public:
    static std::function<void()> onCallBackResult;
    void start(std::function<void()> callback)
    {
        onCallBackResult = callback;
        second();
    }
    static void second() { //Needs to be static here
        onCallBackResult();
    }
};

std::function<void()> Foo::onCallBackResult;

void onCallBackResult() 
{
    std::cout << "Result\n";
}

int main() {
    Foo foo;
    foo.start(std::bind(onCallBackResult));
}
```

But I want to create more than one instance of the same class with diferent functions but since it's declarated here "std::function Foo::onCallBackResult;" it always share the same function not matter where or how I change it in one instance of the class. My doubt here is how can I change it to allow me not to share the same function. Thank you!

Comment: What do you *really* want to do? Have a single function that is different in different places? How about having more than one function? :-)

Comment: By making it non-static? Seriously, it looks like you want it to be static and non-static at the same time. The world does not work like that, programming or not.

Comment: I want to initialize the class and give it a function to handle a response when it ends and the actual code do so, but can only be done with one instance since the std::function is declared outside the class. PD: "Having more than one function" is not always the answer.

I dont want it to be non static, just wanted to know if is there a way to put the function in a vector or something like that to handle it as it start creating instances with an id or something like that

Comment: So, you want to keep it static, and than work against the idea of static? And why does the `std::function` object declared outside the class forces you to make things static?

Comment: I need static because I need to access the main from WndProc with this object and it's always static... I know that dynamic is the oposite to static and it cannot be done directly the way I want. Just wanted to ask for a diferent approach to this situation.

Comment: Alright. Now I think it is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Perhaps you should ask the real problem (X) and find an alternative solution, instead of asking this attempted solution (Y). Your requirements are conflicting each others. Even if you can get an answer, it may not be a good answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think you're using a wrong method to call onCallBackResult function. Could you try this code :

```
    #pragma once #include <functional> 
#include <iostream> class Foo { 
public: std::function<void()> onCallBackResult; 
void start(std::function<void()> callback) { 
onCallBackResult = callback; 
second(); 
} 

void second() { 
//Needs to be static here 
onCallBackResult();
} 
}; 
//std::function<void()> Foo::onCallBackResult; 

void onCallBackResult() { 
std::cout << "Result\n"; 
} 

int main() { 
Foo foo; 
foo.start(std::bind(foo.onCallBackResult)); 
}
```